# Adding website administration tool in Visual Studio 2013 for an ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to use web site administration tool for my project and I have followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

The command

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

works correctly. But when I press

```
localhost:8089/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\Users\kuet_minion\Desktop\mywork\MerchantSite\MerchantSite\ &applicationUrl=/
```

in browser it shows error:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8089.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the link to the tutorial.  I was successful in getting the tool to run.  However, I had a permissions issue on one of the framework directories.

```
Access to the path: 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\....\hash' is denied.
```

I wonder if your firewall is blocking access to it.  Or, perhaps you didn't run the command prompt as Administrator.  Does your browser go through a proxy?